# url cleanup with .htaccess rewrite mode url cleanup

Tags: .htaccess

i have htaccess problem.

i want use htaccess rewrite mode for change this url:

```
http://somedomain.com/?id=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.clashofclans
```

to this:

```
http://somedomain.com/?id=com.supercell.clashofclans
```

I've folowed some .htaccess tutorials but I couldn't. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)?id=(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ /?id=%2 [L,R=301]
```